Google sheets graph current visible series
I'm looking for a function that would find the graph located on the "Frontend" tab and only find me the series i'm using inside that graph.
I'm able to retrieve all series that are connected to that graph, but that's not what i need.
The reason i ask is i want to find the current (2 in this case NEW_rpm and OLD_rpm) series being used, lookup the column of that series apply a MIN and MAX, subtract "100" from MIN and add "100" from MAX and use those to dynamically adjust my graph Y axis.
This is the current code, but it looks at the entire range of all series and applies a min max on the lowest and highest, not the ones being visibly used currently.
function setDynamicGraph() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Frontend');
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0]; // Neem de eerste grafiek op het blad

  var ranges = chart.getRanges();
  var minValues = [];
  var maxValues = [];
  var visibleSeries = [];

  ranges.forEach(function(range) {
    var values = range.getValues();
    var seriesVisible = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
        if (typeof values[i][j] === 'number' && values[i][j] !== 0) {
          minValues.push(values[i][j]);
          maxValues.push(values[i][j]);
          seriesVisible = true;
        }
      }
    }

    if (seriesVisible) {
      var rangeNotation = range.getA1Notation();
      visibleSeries.push(rangeNotation);
    }
  });

  Logger.log('Visible series: ' + visibleSeries.join(', '));

  if (minValues.length === 0 || maxValues.length === 0) {
    Logger.log('Geen numerieke data gevonden in de grafiek.');
    return;
  }

  var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, minValues);
  var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, maxValues);
  
  Logger.log('Huidige laagste datapunt: ' + minValue);
  Logger.log('Huidige hoogste datapunt: ' + maxValue);

  var adjustedMinValue = minValue - 100;
  var adjustedMaxValue = maxValue + 100;

  var newChart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', adjustedMinValue)
    .setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.max', adjustedMaxValue)
    .build();

  sheet.updateChart(newChart);
}

A Link to the current latest version is found here Link to Google Sheets Example
I think you need to copy it to your own drive to be able to see the Apps Script, you can then select "setDynamicGraph" from the dropdown and click run and it should Logger.log the data right there for you.
Can someone help me out please? i have tried everything and nothing works, even tried using chatGPT but it cannot help me.
Thanks in advance.

There are 12 columns in each Range (A:L) so a series could be any one of those 12 columns; one needs to know a specific header value in order to select the relevant column for the series. The header value will be equal to the relevant "series title/name" and/or the "legend" values (for the want of better descriptions). Does the user know these values in advance or is it proposed that they are to be determined by the script? If the latter, then the question can't be solved since there are no commands that will return series and/or legend values.

@Tedinoz apologies i don’t fully understand your questions. Files get uploaded and the titles always remain the same but the values change. The person only edits the chart by adding or removing series as he likes from the 2 ranges (OLD & NEW). The chart should expand or contract on the y-axis to the highest and lowest value of the selected series(not the entire range A-L). Basically like in the example only NEW_RPM and OLD_RPM are used, so i would want my graph to scale according to the lowest and highest values in these 2 columns. Hope this explains it more.

by adding or removing series as he likes from the 2 ranges This is exactly the point that I'm trying to make... say a user chooses "NEW_Boost" & "OLD_Boost"; to get MIN and MAX, the script has to determine that the data is found in Column B of the sheets. But say the next user chooses "NEW_RPM" & "OLD_RPM"  = Column C), and another user chooses "NEW_Turbo" and "OLD_Turbo" (Column L). Theoretically, a script could use indexOf to match the "Series" names (or "Legend" values) BUT there are no apps script commands that will return those values. So there is no way to find the Data column.
